# Присвоение значений ключам именованного кортежа

Tags: python, коллекции, dataset

Можно ли ключам объекта namedtuple присваивать значения по отдельности и как затем вывести список значений?

Пример того, как мне хотелось сделать, присваивать именно по отдельности, так как присвоенные значения -- результаты вызова из БД, что каждый раз при вызове функции должны были бы обновляться:

```
features = namedtuple('Features', ['val1',  'val2', 'val3', 'val4'])

features.val1 = 1690  
features.val2 = 12
features.val3 = 1990
features.val4 = 120
```

И я хотела бы чтоб в итоге было:

```
list(features)
output: [1690, 12, 1990, 120]
```

Но работает только так:

```
features.val1, features.val2 
output: 1690, 12
```

В итоге features -- это **main**.Features, нельзя делать `features._asdict.values()` или `list(features)`, чтобы получить вектор значений.
Я понимаю, что правильно делать так:

```
features = namedtuple('Features', ['val1',  'val2', 'val3', 'val4'])
f = features(val1 = 1690, val2 = 12, val3 = 1990, val4 = 120)
```

Но так, в моем случае совершенно неудобно.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576555/ или [data classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)

Comment: Какой-то просто жесточайший комментарий, я же умру в этом коде, неужели сложно нормально ответить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте хотя бы первые абзацы по ссылкам. Если это не отвечает на ваш вопрос, то уточните почему.

Comment: Если вы не заметили, уровень вопроса -- новичок, уточнение: мне сложно понять тот код и думаю, что мой вопрос можно решить гораздо быстрее простым ответом, нежели я сейчас буду раскапывать китайскую грамоту по ссылкам. Проще уж я в словарь все переведу и все, спасибо.

Comment: Одни из первых строк в ссылках (*The main difference is that records, unlike named tuples, are mutable.*, *Although they use a very different mechanism, Data Classes can be thought of as "mutable namedtuples with defaults"*) означают, что `namedtuple` неизменяемый и для похожей функциональности, но с изменяемыми значениями (как вы указываете в псевдокоде), можно использовать эти два решения.

Comment: да, я поняла, что из-за того, что кортеж тип неизменяемый, я не могу провернуть то, что хочу, я прочитала это по ссылкам уже, просто у меня вылетело это свойство кортежей из головы. Мне просто пока что решения, предложенные вами не вполне ясны, нужно поразбираться, но буду иметь в виду, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто используете тип как объект, а нужно создать экземпляр объекта этого типа:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Features = namedtuple('Features', ['val1',  'val2', 'val3', 'val4'])
features = Features(1690, 12, 1990, 120)
list(features)

[1690, 12, 1990, 120]
```

Как выставить для `namedtuple` значения по умолчанию в разных версиях Python [написано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348004/8324991)

Comment: Я знаю, знаю, я ж об этом пишу ниже, просто мне очень неудобно назначать все сразу значения ключам, вот так: Features(1690, 12, 1990, 120), думала, может можно как-то по иному, наверное проще воспользоваться словарями, спасибо за овет.

Comment: Если у вас Python 3.7, то там уже можно довольно просто. 
 Но можно и в других версиях. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348004/8324991

Comment: сложно, поразбираюсь, спасибо!)

Comment: Но если вам надо менять значения как-то по-отдельности, то лучше да, взять другую структуру. Или всё-таки явно заполнять все поля сразу.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю! Пусть будут словари.